# Cannot open generated database from EF Code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-4

The error I am getting is "Cannot open database "NerdlyDB" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'ComputerName\User Name'.

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="NerdlyDB" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=SSPI; initial catalog= NerdlyDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

This database was generates by using EF code first approach. I am new to this one, so I will show you what I did in case it is off somewhere:

On of my Entity Classes:

```
namespace NerdlyThings.Models
{
public class Post
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
}
}
```

DBContext Class

```
namespace NerdlyThings.Models
{
public class NerdlyDB : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Quote> Quotes { get; set; }
}
}
```

I see that the error is obvious an authentication issue, but I don't know where to set it using code first, only via setting up a db in sql server management studio.

*EDIT***

Ok, so I am not by the computer I originally did this on, but I had some time to kill at work so gave this another go by following the simple instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685467.aspx)

I did this in Visual Studio 2012 RC in an MVC4 internet application template. Works like a dream and I can only assume I have either some strange configuration issue on my other computer, or something got messed up along the way. Anyway here is what I did:

Classes:

```
namespace CodeFirstBlog.Models
{
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string BloggerName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
}
}
```

DBContext Class:

```
namespace CodeFirstBlog.Models
{
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
}
```

I set these up and then created a controller like so (Just had it generated my selecting my context and the class):

```
public class BlogController : Controller
{
    private BlogContext db = new BlogContext();

    //
    // GET: /Blog/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Blogs.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /Blog/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        Blog blog = db.Blogs.Find(id);
        if (blog == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(blog);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Blog/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Blog/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Blog blog)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(blog);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Blog/Edit/5

    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Blog blog = db.Blogs.Find(id);
        if (blog == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(blog);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Blog/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Blog blog)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(blog);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Blog/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
    {
        Blog blog = db.Blogs.Find(id);
        if (blog == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(blog);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Blog/Delete/5

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        Blog blog = db.Blogs.Find(id);
        db.Blogs.Remove(blog);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        db.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Then I simply ran the application, used the generated views to create a new Blog. Works great. The database was generated in my App_Data folder, I can access it fine and see the generated schema. So problem solved, maybe? From this point I can use your suggested answers to tweak db settings and whatnot, so thank you.

Comment: Im not 100% sure but try running this as admin instead, its using the localdb with your current user so it shouldn't have a permissions issue. You can also connect to (LocalDb)\v11.0 via SSMS which will let you look at the actual permissions

Comment: Hm.. If I try to connect to localdb in SSMS it gives me this error: "Property Login was not set"

Comment: You could try rebuilding your local db as outlined here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/LightSwitchDev11Beta/thread/484fb538-81eb-4eb6-b0bd-980dc85c5f7e

Comment: sweet, I was looking around for how to do that. I had to step away from the project last night, but i will give this a go tonight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach I have found so far is to create my own [IDatabaseInitializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) to run commands that I need to create indices and create users.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static private Initializer DbInitializer;
    static MyContext()
    {
        DbInitializer = new MyContext.Initializer();
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(DbInitializer);
    }
}
public class Initializer : IDatabaseInitializer<MyContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(MyContext context)
    {
        string ddl = "(Some SQL command to e.g. create an index or create a user)";
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(ddl);
    }
}
```

Comment: I definitely liking this idea, I am working on implementing it now.

Comment: In my actual code, I have a `List<string>` of DDL commands and execute each of them in a loop.  Makes it easy to keep all DDL in one place.

Comment: Check my rather long edit to see how this all panned out for me. Not sure what was causing the original issue, will have to investigate, but i for sure like your answer here to give me finer control over generating the db. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you connecting your `DBContext` class to that connection string somewhere? My guess is that is missing and therefore causing the problem. I've usually seen the connection string specified in the constructor of the `DBContext` class (see example below):

```
public class NerdlyDB : DbContext
{
    public NerdlyDB() : base("NerdlyDB")
    {
    }
    ...
```

This will then look for a `<connectionString>` with `name="NerdlyDB"` in your `web.config` / `app.config`. See this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-2-connections-and-models.aspx) for more info on setting up EF with your connection string.

I would also recommend using @Eric J.'s approach in your code. You can see a pretty in depth example of his suggestion (and EF code first in general) at [silk.codeplex.com](http://silk.codeplex.com) (specifically the `MileageStats.Data.SqlCe` project)

On a separate note, it looks like you are missing the actual code first model setup. Check out the [`MileageStatsDbContext.cs`](http://silk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/d380cf634c1b#MileageStats/MileageStats.Data.SqlCe/MileageStatsDbContext.cs) file in the `Silk` project to see an example of how to do that.